# Need for loading of expl3 code?

Tags: pstricks, expl3, minimal

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

% Self-brewed macro.
\def\andel#1{%
  \calculate{#1/(\Nord+\MidtVest+\Oestjylland+\Syd+\Fyn+\Oest+\Bornholm+\Lorry)*100}
}
\def\seere#1#2{%
  \psframe[dimen=middel,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!45]%
    (!2 #1 mul 1 sub \bredde 2 div sub 0)%
    (!2 #1 mul 1 sub \bredde 2 div add #2)
  \rput(!2 #1 mul 1 sub #2 5 add){\scriptsize\num{#2 000}}
  \rput{90}(!2 #1 mul 1 sub #2 2 div){%
    \scriptsize\SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=1]{\andel{#2}}{\percent}%
  }
}

% PSTricks stuff from Herbert.
\makeatletter
 \def\pst@@@vlabel#1{%
   \edef\@xyDecimals{\psk@yDecimals}%
   \ifodd\psk@labels % labelss=all||y (0,2)
   \else%
     \ifnum#1=0 \psvlabel{\expandafter\@LabelComma#1..\@nil}%
     \else \psvlabel{\expandafter\@LabelComma#1..\@nil\psk@ylabelFactor}%
     \fi
   \fi%
}%
\makeatother

% LaTeX 3 syntax.
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calculate \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
% Column width.
\def\bredde{0.7 }
% Constants.
\def\Nord{86}
\def\MidtVest{87}
\def\Oestjylland{107}
\def\Syd{147}
\def\Fyn{102}
\def\Oest{125}
\def\Bornholm{16}
\def\Lorry{210}
 % Settings.
 \centering
 \psset{xunit=0.56cm,yunit=0.04cm}
  % Drawing.
  \begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-42)(19.1,238)
   \psaxes[
     xAxis=false,
     Dy=20,
     dy=20,
     ylabelFactor={\cdot 10^3}
   ]{->}(0,0)(16,230)
   \psaxes[
     yAxis=false,
     ticks=none,
     mathLabel=false,
     xLabels={
      ,Nord,
      ,Midt-Vest,
      ,{\O}stjylland,
      ,Syd,
      ,Fyn,
      ,{\O}st,
      ,Bornholm,
      ,Lorry,
     },
    xLabelsRot=90
   ]{->}(0,0)(16,230)[Tv-stationer,0][Seere,90]
   \multido{\i=20+20}{11}{\psline[linestyle=dotted](0,\i)(16,\i)}
   \seere{1}{\Nord}
   \seere{2}{\MidtVest}
   \seere{3}{\Oestjylland}
   \seere{4}{\Syd}
   \seere{5}{\Fyn}
   \seere{6}{\Oest}
   \seere{7}{\Bornholm}
   \seere{8}{\Lorry}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Is it possible to make the calculations in the `\andel` macro and use it in the `\SI` macro without having to load the following code?

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calculate \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: `\expandafter\let\expandafter\calculate\csname fp_eval:n\endcsname` will do the same; what's bothering you?

Comment: @egreg Nothing in particular. I was just wondering it if is possible to get rid of that bit of code and still do the same calculations. (I try to minimize the code I have to write myself, that is all `:)`.)

Comment: `\fp_eval:n` is very powerful and perhaps there will be a user interface to it, which there isn't at present.

Comment: Note that I wrote `siunitx` before we had the FPU, and the original _intention_ was that the arguments would be 'pure' numbers. There is of course now an argument for making them 'calculation-aware', perhaps as part of my ideas to allow switching of the parser (or in parallel).

Comment: More broadly, `\fp_eval:n` is code-level and ideally should be 'incorporated' into user interfaces in a transparent way (_cf._ use of `pgfmath` implicitly by many `pgf` commands)

Comment: @JosephWright Nice explanation/information; thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code for being able to use `\fp_eval:n` is already loaded by `siunitx`. The problem is just getting at it; it's not possible to use `\fp_eval:n` in the normal environment, because it is not a legal control sequence name at the user level.

The `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` commands set up TeX for making `\fp_eval:n` a legal control sequence name, like the traditional `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands that allow using commands with `@` in their name. Thus

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \calculate \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

defines a “user level” interface to the powerful computation function. If you are afraid if it, an equivalent way is

```
\expandafter\let\expandafter\calculate\csname fp_eval:n\endcsname
```